# Standard Method to calculate Average Moving Speed from Times & Coords?

Tags: coordinates, algorithm, analysis, calculate-values

<sup>*...I wasn't sure if this question was best suited to [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/), so after reading [GIS Topics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I decided to ask here, but I'll relocate if necessary...*  **:-)**</sup>

---

I'm working on automating various analyses of movement and activities based on various sizable (50K→500K) sets of **datetime/latitude/longitude** data.

I'd like to determine ***"Average Moving Speed"***.

1. Parts of the recordset will have little or no movement
2. Other parts will have movement of varying speeds (ie., walking or driving), and,
3. A few records will (frustratingly) contain what I assume are GPS errors: Sudden "hops" to an unrealistic distance, returning to the previous location in the following record.

Is there a **standard** method of determining **Average Moving Speed**?

- Perhaps a minimum distance that is considered "actual movement" as opposed to GPS resolution or reporting issues, or
- Maybe there is a standard formula or algorithm that I haven't found yet.

I'm comfortable with coding and I've brainstormed and experimented with a few methods but each seems to have it's own issues.

---

**Possible methods:**

- Skipping every ***n*** records  (Surely the worst option.)
- Skipping records between "whole minutes" or "whole 3 minutes" etc (Some legitimate movement would be missed.)
- An interpretation of **Rolling Average**.

I figure that once I can extrapolate Average Moving Speed, I will be able to deduce **Activity Type** -- ie., whether the movement was most likely walking, driving, flying, idle, etc... but I'd be interested to hear thoughts about that as well.

---

From what I understand *Rolling Average* would be, instead of looking at the current record, take an average of ***n*** records *before* and ***n*** records *after* the current record.

If that's the case, there could still be various interpretations:

- Take separate averages of the `n + n + 1` Lon's & Lat's and use those numbers to calculate movement
- Averages of each `n + n + 1` records elapsed time, divided by Averages of each `n + n + 1` records' distance traveled
- I will try out any ideas you may have and report my findings back here.

An example of the data (with distance [meters] and time [seconds] added, at individual-record level):   (and [this link](http://jmp.sh/dsk5lTN) to a downloadable 200-record CSV sample)

[image: example data]

Some **places I've looked for insight** (without success, unless I missed something):

- [How to best measure average speed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73941/how-best-to-measure-average-speed)
- [How can I calculate the average speed in various legs of a bus route](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78768/how-can-i-calculate-the-average-speed-in-various-legs-of-a-bus-route)
- [Delayed Moving Average](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90343/delayed-moving-average)
- Wikipedia: [Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)